# render tag selector content in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm scratching the surface of angular2 using angular cli interface for init simple project.

I successfully create project but when I add new component using `ng generate component test`
component is created like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {    
  constructor() { }    
  ngOnInit() {
  }    
}
```

but what confuse me is that I cannot render anything (except Loading) under `<test>Loading</test>` selector which I put index.html right after rendering app-root

```
 <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
 <test>Loading ...</test>

test.component.html
<p>
  test works!
</p>
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Update:
Main module is aware of this component cause angularcli adding that and all the imports automatically

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, TestComponent
  ],
```

Update 2:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Comment: Have included all the components in `app.module.ts`? What files do you have like, `main.ts`, `app.module.ts`, `app.component.ts`?

Comment: yes, all is included by the angular cli tool.

Comment: Your main module (basicaly called app.module.ts) needs to know about every component before you can use them. So as @CharanCherry already mentioned, did you import that?

Comment: can you show me the `app-root` component code?

Comment: have you tried by adding `<test>Loading ...</test>` inside `app.component.html` and removing from `index.html` ? are you getting any error ?

Comment: Stupid question, but maybe it's missing: You've any content in `./test.component.html`?

Comment: yes, I have, I posted already in the question body :)

Comment: No, what html code do you have in  `./test.component.html`? Haven't posted yet

Comment: yes I have posted, it's <p>test works</p>

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: no I double checked. nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason is you need to bootstrap both the components in order to include both of them in `index.html`. Or you can bootstrap app component and include the test component in app component.

**Answer1:**

app.module.ts

```
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, 
    TestComponent
  ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent, TestComponent ]
```

**Answer2:**

```
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

then include the testcomponent i.e., `<test>` in app component's template

Ex: if below is `app.component.html` code

```
<h1>app component</h1>
```

chnage it to

```
<h1>app component</h1>
<test></test>
```

to include test component

Comment: I belive bootstrapping only AppComponent is more natural way, at least I see it that way. So how can I include test component inside appcomponent?

Comment: Since @Charan Cherry answered before me, I'll just answer here as well. @user1765862 you just have you move your `<test>` tag into `app.component.html`. Simply add that tag somewhere in your components html file and it's all done.

Answer (score 1):

No need to slay me.... but you can try to Remove `<app-root></app-root>` and just render test, and try if your "test" renders as should :)

Comment: you must be kidding.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem tbh. Angular provides using multiple selectors in a single template.

Comment: @user1765862 Just shows the loading text on my app that component, so I don't know. No need to slay me :D  Ok Aer0 I believe you. Just a test on my app and I received the same problem, so at least that can be tested, right?

Comment: @user1765862 Did you even try it? I'll go ahead and remove this answer then if it was so stupid ;)

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging into plnkr and how to set up an Angular live example, I've got the answer. Basically, @AJT_82 was partly right with his answer.

Since Angular 2 you have to call the Framework which of your selectors is the root one you want to bootstrap. This part is handled by the following line in your `app.module.ts` file.

```
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

As you can see, Angular will try to bootstrap your AppComponent, which basically means it's trying to load your AppComponent as a (there can be more) root element inside of your `index.html`. To get Angular looking up for more modules, you just have to add the next ones too.

```
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent, TestComponent ]
```

If you're only bootstrapping AppComponent, you can also move your `<test></test>` tag into `app.component.html` which will basically lead to the same result.

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wt5XnIHkfVO9NJmkz4nS?p=preview)